# Trace-zero functions in $W^{1,p}$.

Tags: partial-differential-equations, sobolev-spaces, trace

I want to Prove the following Theorem.

**Theorem : Trace-zero functions in $W^{1,p}$.**(Evans 259p).
Assume $U$ is bounded and $\partial U$ is $C^1$. Suppose that $u\in W^{1,p}$. Then

$$u\in W^{1,p}_0\Leftrightarrow Tu=0\text{ on }\partial U$$

The proof of the ($\Leftarrow$) direction use partitions of unity and the flattening of $\partial U$. So one can assume
$$U=\mathbb{R}_n^+=\mathbb{R}^{n-1}\times \mathbb{R}_+.$$
and
$$ u\in W^{1,p}_0,~u\text{ has compact support in }\bar{\mathbb{R}}_+^n$$
$$Tu=0\text{ on }\partial\mathbb{R}_+^n=\mathbb{R}^{n-1}.$$

I understand all calculations in the proof but I can't understand the assumption.
I want to know why I can make such an assumption.

Comment: Do you understand how "flattening the boundary" works?

Comment: how to prove using partitions of unity that $u \in W^{1,p}(\mathbb{R}^n_+)$, $u$ has compact support and $Tu=0$ on $\partial\mathbb{R}^n_+$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that your problem is with partition of unity, i.e. how a global statement is prooved on small pieces.

Assuming $Tu= 0\ $ on $\partial U$, one wants to show $u \in W_0^{1,p}(U)$. This space is defined a few pages before (p.259 in the 2010 edition) as the closure of $C^{\infty}_c(U)$, i.e. $\exists\, (u_m)_{m\in \mathbb{N}},\ u_m\in C^{\infty}_c(U)$ such that 
$$\lim_{m\rightarrow \infty} \lVert u_m - u \rVert_{W^{1,p}(U)}=0 \tag{1}$$

Having a partition of unity allows us to write something of the form (cf. a few pages before § 5.3.2, Thm 2 p.265 in the 2010 edition, "global approximation by smooth functions)
$$ u \equiv 1 \times u \equiv \sum_{i=0}^{+\infty} \zeta_i u \tag{2}$$
(I write $\equiv$ to mean equality as a function, i.e. equality at each point. The sum p.265 is subordinated to some open cover $\{V_i\}_{i\in \mathbb{N}}$ but in our case it can even be chosen finite by compactness of $\partial U$) with a condition on Support$(\zeta_i u)$.

The calculations (that you understand...) show
$$\lim_{m\rightarrow \infty} \lVert \zeta_i (u_m - u) \rVert_{W^{1,p}(U)}=0 \tag{1}$$

Either one has a finite sum in (2) and one obtains (1), either the sum is infinite and one needs a stronger condition, example adapted from p.265-266 (2010 edition), $\forall\ \epsilon > 0,\ \exists N_i \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $$\lVert \zeta_i (u_p - u) \rVert_{W^{1,p}(U)} \leq \frac{\epsilon}{2^{i+1}},\quad \forall\ p\geq N_i$$
to obtain (1).

One cannot skip the use of partition of unity because the very definition of "$\partial U$ is $C^1$" is formulated locally.